# Finding the location of mobile number in blackberry while getting call?

Tags: blackberry, mobile, call, blackberry-jde

i want to find the location of a mobile number from where i am getting the call in blackberry. is it possible. if yes, can you guys redirect me to some links or provide me some samples which will help me to go ahead with my idea.

Comment: Did you got any solution for your question? I am also want same requirement, If you got it provide some links and let me know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can know the number that called you ... not the location of the mobile number. Then you can know from where you are getting the call from the number of the caller

Comment: Hey Farid..  once i get the cell no and caller name (if exist in phone book ) what else i have to do to know about the location of an phone number. can i use GPS. please provide me some input with some link to sample codes.

Comment: When getting the number and the caller name from a phone call, this will be as a String for you representing the caller, so you cannot (as far as I know) get the location of the call